# How to reference a widget from fragment layout which is not yet present in UI

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using SlidingPane layout for master/detail kind of UI. Detail pane is a fragment which contains among other widgets ListView a would like to reference and set OnItemClickListener on it. Problem is that ListView (R.id.lvDetailsListView) is not yet present in UI until user selects particular option in Master Pane. How to reference widget from fragment?

Here is how  I tried, but I get NullPointerException:

```
masterList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                masterItemsByStore = new GetMasterItemsByStore();

                // Remove info label on store select
                if(selectStoreLabel.getVisibility() != 8){
                    selectStoreLabel.setVisibility(8);              
                }

                TextView tvStoreID = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvStoreID);
                String store_id = tvStoreID.getText().toString();
                TextView tvStoreName = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvStoreName);
                String store_name = tvStoreName.getText().toString();
                TextView tvStoreAddress = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvStoreCity);
                String store_address = tvStoreAddress.getText().toString();
                setTitle(store_name);

                fragment = new StoreItemsFragment(store_id, store_name,
                        store_address);

                detailsList = (ListView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.lvDetailsListView);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.detail_pane, fragment).commit();

                slidingPane.closePane();

                detailsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        detailPane.getForeground().setAlpha(200);
                        popWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.TOP, 0, 150);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can't (and you shouldn', actually). It depends on your architecture, but chances are the list view isn't even created yet when you initialize the app. Assign the click listener when you create the detail view, and not when the app first loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing that inside of your fragment

For example in your `StoreItemsFragment`:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedState) {
    // Inflate fragment's layout and prepare parent, list variables
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    ListView detailsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvDetailsListView);
    detailsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((YourActivity)getActivity()).detailPane.getForeground().setAlpha(200);
            ((YourActivity)getActivity()).popWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.TOP, 0, 150);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I assume here that your activity is created before the fragment, and that `detailPane` and `popWindow` are public variables.

Comment: Yeah you right, inside onCreateView method. I don't know I missed that but I guess it comes with experience, thanks :)